A publicly accessible place to photo Cologne Cathedral's west facade
Do you know of any publicly accessible place in Cologne where I can photograph Cologne Cathedral's entire west facade in a single frame? See examples below.
The Cathedral's west square is not a good place for that because of the angle which creates very conspicuous perspective distortion and requires a very wide lens (10-20 mm would barely suffice).
Regarding lens and camera: I have an 18-200 mm Nikkor lens and a "crop sensor" Nikkon D7100.
The Colonium TV tower could be a very good candidate but as of 2023, it is closed to the public. There also might be buildings with publicly accessible roofs with a view of the cathedral's west facade, but I don't know of them, hence, my question.
Examples


Sources: Wikipedia - https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Koeln_in_Bildern,_Tafel_6._Der_Dom._Westseite.jpg and https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Golden-Cologne-Cathedral-01.jpg

You may not be able to get this from outside a building.

Can you borrow/rent a tilt-shift lens?

@JonCuster There is no need to use a tilt-shift lens with digital photography, as you can correct the perspective digitally at a later stage. There are however still limits on how much you can correct and no way to achieve something similar to these two examples if you stand on the square directly in front of the church.

Providing a corrected optical image to the digital sensor is going to be much better than correcting digitally afterward.

The first picture is probably taken from the tower of the St. Andreas church. Even if the tower is not usually accessible to the public, if this is important for you, I would have contacted them and asked if it is somehow possible to arrange a visit. Churches are often doing a lot if you wag with a donation.
The second picture must have been taken from the roof of the WDR building across Nord-Süd-Fahrt, or perhaps from an office window at one of the upper floors. These areas are not publicly accessible.
Except for the St. Andreas church, I don't see any other possibility to get a photo similar to the examples you are posting.

Another option might be to use a drone, if legal.

@WeatherVane It is not and therefore I did not mention it.

Are you not allowed to use a lightweight drone (below 250g) even if there are people on the square? For example https://so-stadt.de/so-koeln/news/10-orte-an-denen-in-koeln-keine-drohnen-fliegen-duerfen (in German) lists that you are not allowed to fly a drone above 120m at the church, not that you are forbidden from flying it there at all.

@Zibelas There have been a lot of changes recently in the legislation and I might be mistaken, but there are several restriction zones around the cathedral caused by a nearby police station, a federal police office, industrial, power supply and railway facilities. AFAIK, you are not allowed to fly in these zones, not even with lightweight drones.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thank you. I approached the Church by e-mail.
